# Load image in Picasso from JSON

Tags: android, json, string, crud, picasso

I want to load an image in Picasso from a url that is stored in the MySQL database.
But the code returning is in JSON and I can't get it working.

When putting a direct link instead of TAG_IMAGE it shows an image without any problem (so picasso itself is working with Strings).

How can I parse a JSON to a string, so Picasso can load it?

**EDIT**
TAG_IMAGE needs to be converted to a String (answer by Punit).

**Code:**

```
import ...

public class ViewRecipeActivity extends Activity {

TextView txtName;
TextView txtTime;
TextView txtPrice;
TextView txtDesc;
ImageView imagePhoto;
TextView txtCreatedAt;

String pid;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// single product url
private static final String url_recipe_details = "phpfiletoloadall.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_RECIPE = "recipes";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_TIME = "time";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "image";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_recipe);

    //toolbar back button
    ImageView btnBack = findViewById( R.id.btnBack );
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ViewRecipeActivity.this, ActivityTwo.class));
            finish();
            }
            }
    );


    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)      findViewById(R.id.bottomNavView_Bar);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
    Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(2);
    menuItem.setChecked(true);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.ic_home:
                    Intent intent0 = new Intent(ViewRecipeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent0);
                    finish();
                    break;

                case R.id.ic_ingredients:
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(ViewRecipeActivity.this, ActivityOne.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    finish();
                    break;

                case R.id.ic_dining:

                    break;

                case R.id.ic_center_focus:
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(ViewRecipeActivity.this, ActivityThree.class);
                    startActivity(intent3);
                    finish();
                    break;

                case R.id.ic_backup:
                    Intent intent4 = new Intent(ViewRecipeActivity.this, ActivityFour.class);
                    startActivity(intent4);
                    finish();
                    break;
            }


            return false;
        }
    });

    //Make network connect access (temp)
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    // Make textview scrollable
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);
    textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    // getting product details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting product id (pid) from intent
    pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

    // Getting complete product details in background thread
    new GetProductDetails().execute();

    }
    /**
 * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
 * */
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ViewRecipeActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading recipe details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {

                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_recipe_details, "GET", params);


                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single Recipe Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_RECIPE); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        // product with this pid found
                        // Edit Text
                        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                        txtDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);
                        imagePhoto = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.imagePhoto );

                        // display product data in EditText
                        txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                        txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
                        Picasso.get().load(TAG_IMAGE).into(imagePhoto);

                        Log.d("good", "shows recipe");
                    }else{
                        // product with pid not found
                        Log.d("bad", "recipe not found");
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;

    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully received product details
                    JSONArray productObj = json
                            .getJSONArray(TAG_RECIPE); // JSON Array

                    // get first product object from JSON Array
                    JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                    // product with this pid found
                    // Edit Text
                    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                    txtDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);
                    imagePhoto = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.imagePhoto );

                    // display product data in EditText
                    txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                    txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
                    Picasso.get().load(product.getString(TAG_IMAGE)).into(imagePhoto);

                    Log.d("good", "shows recipe");
                }
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple but couldn't find the line                     Picasso.get().load(product.getString(TAG_IMAGE)).into(imagePhoto);

Comment: Now only the other screen with map.put function in it :/

Answer (score 0):

You are using `TAG_IMAGE` which is `String` variable name of tag. So you have to get image url from json using this tag just like you did for get name `TAG_NAME` and description `TAG_DESCRIPTION`.

get Image Url

```
String imageUrl = product.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(imagePhoto);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy,

```
 Picasso.with(this)
 .load(TAG_IMAGE)
 .error(R.mipmap.no_image_available)
 .into(imagePhoto);
```

When your image is not load, and get some error that time display error part

Answer (score 0):

You can use it

```
   Picasso.with(this)
   .load(TAG_IMAGE)
   .into(imagePhoto);
```